# C++ initialization of global variables

Tags: c++, raii

In C++ what would be the best way to have an object that needs to be initalized in main(), but has to be global, so it can be accessed from other functions throughout the program? And make sure the destructor is called to make sure it gets cleaned up properly?

Comment: are you allocating the object on the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct foo {};

foo *x_ptr;

int main() {
    foo x;
    x_ptr = &x;
    // the rest
}
```

You can also use `std::reference_wrapper` if you don't want to access members via `operator->`.

But really, don't do that. Pass it along if it's needed, instead of making it global, e.g.

```
void needs_foo1(foo&);
void needs_foo2(foo&, int, int, int); 

int main() {
    foo x;
    needs_foo1(x);
    needs_foo2(x, 1, 2, 3);
    // et cetera
}
```

Comment: The reason why he says don't do that is because having a global variable that anything can modify can become really dangerous in a complex system where you don't know what entity is changing it; can get really hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that "global" is a solution rather than a requirement. As it has been suggested you could always pass your object around explicitly.

If you don't want to do that I'd probably use a [`shared::ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), possibly wrapped in a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) implementation. Your `shared_ptr` would be initialized to `null` at program start-up and set to a valid value in `main()`.

Beware that you may encounter order of destruction problems if you have global variables that depend on other global variables. There's also a huge literature about the drawbacks of the Singleton patterns.

Comment: Yes, I can't imagine globals being a requirement. Just make one and pass it around. Be explicit about dependencies.